# Code reacts too slow for motors to react

Tags: arduino, robot

I am building an inverted pendulum robot. After analyzing what others have created I came to the conclusion that my code is way too slow. I am looking for suggestions to improve the code I wrote. I have some speculations regarding as to which direction to head in. I am using an Arduino Nano Esp32 with A4998 and Nema 17. PSU is 12V 2.4A.Thank you for taking your time to read this. Here are my ideas:

1. Interrupts for the MPU6050
2. Implement my own form of motor control that is non blocking and uses interrupts. Here I am a little bewildered, because I do not know if I should have an implementation that pulses the motors every time the loop is executed, or do I implement some sort of motor control that works in realtime, compares the previous speed with the "new" speed and acts accordingly.

Update: After browsing the code improvement tips I have made some improvements to the code. I have uploaded it to the robot and confirmed it to be working but the steppers still react too slow. There is a slight improvement in the response time.

```
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <PID_v1.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu;

int MPU_addr = 0x68;

float const_calib_X = 0 ;
float const_calib_Y = 0 ;
float const_calib_Z = 0.2;

#define dirPin_X  2
#define stepPin_X 5

#define dirPin_Y  3  //3 Y //4 Z
#define stepPin_Y 6  //6 Y //7 Z

#define enablePin 8

//PID
double Kp = 10;
double Ki = 0;
double Kd = 0;
double Setpoint = 0;


double input=0;
double output=0;
double setpoint=0;
double  angle_correction=0.5;

PID myPID(&input, &output, &setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);

float unghi; //trimite valoarea unghiului de la accelerometru

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  
const int pulsesPerRevolution = 200;

int motorSpeed1;
int motorSpeed2;

unsigned long prevMillis = 0;
int revolutions = 0;

int led_R = 14;
int led_G = 15;
int led_B = 16;

float RateRoll, RatePitch, RateYaw;
float RateCalibrationRoll, RateCalibrationPitch, RateCalibrationYaw;
int RateCalibrationNumber;
float AccX, AccY, AccZ;
float AngleRoll, AnglePitch;
uint32_t LoopTimer;
float KalmanAngleRoll=0, KalmanUncertaintyAngleRoll=2*2;
float KalmanAnglePitch=0, KalmanUncertaintyAnglePitch=2*2;
float Kalman1DOutput[]={0,0};

int output_PID = 0;

// AccelStepper instante
AccelStepper stepper1(1, stepPin_X, dirPin_X);
AccelStepper stepper2(1, stepPin_Y, dirPin_Y);

// FIlter smoothing angle
const float alpha_angle_filter = 1;

// MPU
float filteredAnglePitch = 0.0;

// TIMING 

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const int interval = 1000; // Print every 1 second

bool PID_parameters_changed = false;

void timer()  {

unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) 
  {
    Serial.print("Loop execution time: ");
    Serial.print(currentMillis - previousMillis);
    Serial.println(" milliseconds");
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }

}

 void gyro_signals() {
  const float GYRO_SENSITIVITY = 65.5; // Gyro sensitivity: 65.5 LSB/°/s
  const float ACC_SENSITIVITY = 4096.0; // Accelerometer sensitivity: 4096 LSB/g

  // Accelerometer readings
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x3B); // Start with high byte from accelerometer X register
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68, 6); // Read 6 bytes

  int16_t AccXLSB = (Wire.read() << 8) | Wire.read();
  int16_t AccYLSB = (Wire.read() << 8) | Wire.read();
  int16_t AccZLSB = (Wire.read() << 8) | Wire.read();

  // Gyroscope readings
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x43); // Start with high byte from gyroscope X register
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68, 6); // Read 6 bytes

  int16_t GyroX = (Wire.read() << 8) | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroY = (Wire.read() << 8) | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroZ = (Wire.read() << 8) | Wire.read();

  // Convert to useful values
  RateRoll = GyroX / GYRO_SENSITIVITY;
  RatePitch = GyroY / GYRO_SENSITIVITY;
  RateYaw = GyroZ / GYRO_SENSITIVITY;

  AccX = AccXLSB / ACC_SENSITIVITY;
  AccY = AccYLSB / ACC_SENSITIVITY;
  AccZ = (AccZLSB / ACC_SENSITIVITY) - const_calib_Z;

  // Calculate Pitch angle (degrees)
  float AccMagnitude = sqrt(AccX * AccX + AccY * AccY);
  AnglePitch = atan(AccZ / AccMagnitude) * (180.0 / PI);

  // Apply filters and corrections
  filteredAnglePitch = (alpha_angle_filter * AnglePitch + (1 - alpha_angle_filter) * filteredAnglePitch) * 10;
  filteredAnglePitch -= angle_correction * 10;

  // Convert to integer with one decimal point of precision
  filteredAnglePitch = round(filteredAnglePitch);
  filteredAnglePitch /= 10;
}

void moveRobot()
{
    const int minSpeed = 50; // MINIMUM ROBOT SPEED

    // Calculate base motor speed
    int baseSpeed = minSpeed + output; //scos static_cast<int>(output);

    // Adjust motor speeds based on pitch angle
    int motorSpeed1 = filteredAnglePitch > 0 ? -baseSpeed : baseSpeed;
    int motorSpeed2 = filteredAnglePitch > 0 ? baseSpeed : -baseSpeed;

    // Set motor speeds
    stepper1.setSpeed(motorSpeed1);
    stepper2.setSpeed(motorSpeed2);

    // Move motors
    stepper1.runSpeed();
    stepper2.runSpeed();

}

void updatePIDValues() 
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    String inputString = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    inputString.trim();

    if (inputString.startsWith("Kp=")) {
      Kp = inputString.substring(3).toFloat();
    } else if (inputString.startsWith("Ki=")) {
      Ki = inputString.substring(3).toFloat();
    } else if (inputString.startsWith("Kd=")) {
      Kd = inputString.substring(3).toFloat();
    } else if (inputString.startsWith("Setpoint=")) {
      Setpoint = inputString.substring(9).toFloat();
    } 

    Serial.println("Updated PID Values:");
    Serial.print("Kp: "); Serial.println(Kp);
    Serial.print("Ki: "); Serial.println(Ki);
    Serial.print("Kd: "); Serial.println(Kd);
    Serial.print("Setpoint: "); Serial.println(Setpoint);
    Serial.print("Angle_correction: "); Serial.println(angle_correction);
    Serial.print("Final_Angle: "); Serial.println(filteredAnglePitch);
  }
}


void setup() {

  pinMode(led_R,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_G,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_B,OUTPUT);
 
  //KALMAN+MPU START
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // while (!Serial);
 
  if (!mpu.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Sensor init failed");
    while (1)
      yield();
      digitalWrite(led_R,HIGH);
  }
  Serial.println("Found a MPU6050 sensor");

  Wire.begin(); // Initialize I2C communication

  // Setup MPU6050 configuration
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1A); // Power management register 1
  Wire.write(0x05); // Reset and select clock source
  Wire.write(0x1C); // Gyro config register
  Wire.write(0x10); // Set full-scale range to ±1000 degrees per second
  Wire.endTransmission(); ///
 
  for (RateCalibrationNumber=0; RateCalibrationNumber<1000; RateCalibrationNumber ++) {
    gyro_signals();
    RateCalibrationRoll+=RateRoll;
    RateCalibrationPitch+=RatePitch;
    RateCalibrationYaw+=RateYaw;
    delay(1);
  }
  RateCalibrationRoll/=1000;
  RateCalibrationPitch/=1000;
  RateCalibrationYaw/=1000;
  LoopTimer=micros();
  // KALMAN+MPU FINISH

  //CNC SHIELD
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);  
  digitalWrite(enablePin, LOW); //LOW=PORNIT

  //MOTORS
  pinMode(stepPin_X, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin_X, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin_Y, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin_Y, OUTPUT);
 
  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(1000);
  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(1000);
 
  pinMode(led_R,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_G,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_B,OUTPUT);

  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  myPID.SetOutputLimits(-1000, 1000);
 
}


void loop() {

  //timer();

  //int freq = ESP.getCpuFreqMHz();

 
// Check if new PID parameters are available
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    updatePIDValues();  // Update PID parameters from Serial
    PID_parameters_changed = true;  // Set flag to true indicating new parameters
  }

  // If PID parameters have changed, update the PID controller with new values
  if (PID_parameters_changed) {
    myPID.SetTunings(Kp, Ki, Kd);  // Set new PID parameters
    PID_parameters_changed = false;  // Reset the flag
  }

  // Read gyro signals
  gyro_signals();

  // Calculate error in PID
  double err_in_PID = filteredAnglePitch - Setpoint;  // Using Setpoint instead of setpoint

  input = abs(err_in_PID);

  // Compute PID output
  myPID.Compute();

  // Get output from PID controller
  // In the future maybe change the motor control logic
  // Just use one speed and get the sign of the angle to control direction pins
  output_PID = output;
  motorSpeed1 = output;
  motorSpeed2 = output;

  // Move the robot based on PID output
  moveRobot();

  // Print motor speeds for diagnostics
  //Serial.println(motorSpeed1);
  //Serial.println(motorSpeed2);
  


}
```

Comment: Have you looked into doing some sort of "code coverage" , or "code analysis" to see, and pin point, ***where*** exactly it is being slow? See this question, [Analyzing Code for Efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890222/4424636), it *might* help (maybe), or at least give you some ideas.

Comment: @Greenonline Thank your for your answer. I am going to consider this strongly now, as I take a break from the project while gathering ideas. As for that thread, thank you for recommending it to me. I found a ton of useful tips there. It looks like my search function missed it :(

Comment: Hi. It isn't really an answer, just a comment. I can post it as an answer if you want..?